Font newtxtte not found
I am on a new macbook with a fresh TexLive 2024 installation and am trying for the first time on this machine to compile this specific journal template. The compilation fails with the error Font newtxtte at 600 not found. I did not have this problem on my previous Ubuntu machine with an older TexLive version (between 2021 and 2023; I don't have access to that laptop right now to check). I have traced the problem to the option zerostyle=e when loading newtxtt. The other possible options (a, b, c, d, nor not specified) work without problem.
MWE:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[zerostyle=e]{newtxtt}
\begin{document}
\texttt{0}
\end{document}

Full output from running pdflatex test.tex:
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.26 (TeX Live 2024) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./test.tex
LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> patch level 1
L3 programming layer <2024-02-20>
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/newtxtt/newtxtt.sty
`newtxtt' v1.051, 2014/12/23 Typewriter text macros based on txfonts (msharpe)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/textcomp.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex)))))
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def)
(./test.aux) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/newtxtt/t1newtxtt.fd
) [1{/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}{/usr
/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/cm-super/cm-super-t1.enc}]
(./test.aux)
kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 1+0/600 --dpi 600 newtxtte
mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for newtxtte.
mktexpk: perhaps newtxtte is missing from the map file.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.
 )
!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file newtxtte): Font newtxtte at 600 not found
 ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!


I get no error in texlive 2024 but after pdftex.map my terminal shows /usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/newtxtt/txttEec.enc which you don't appear to have

At first check for updates.

@DavidCarlisle The file exists on my system, and seems to look correct (i.e. the only difference to txttAec.enc is the name at the very top and the line starting with /zero.alt.

@UlrikeFischer What exactly should I update, and how do I do that?

as ulrike says you coudl update your system, you don't show the package versions but for example you are using a 2023 latex format so have not updated since june 2024 at least

Where exactly is txttAec.enc on your system? Just to rule out that you have two latex installattions.

@daleif In the exact same location as pointed out by David.

the basic texlive command would be tlmgr update --all (didn't you install mactex which gives some more mac utilities to help manage that sort of thing, but I don't have a mac to giv edetails)

I'm running the update at the moment. Just for reference: Searching for "update MacTex" leads first to "you can't update MacTex". The linked question "How do I update my TeX distribution" does a better job of explaining what I can and cannot update, and provides the same command given by David.

Updating solves the problem. Thanks for the help! It has been a couple of years since I have been last active on this site, and maybe I should I have read "What topics can I ask about here?" which would have pointed me to the useful update post. Should I post an answer, or close/delete the question as not useful?

usually we close questions about issues used by outdated software, but there's no reason to delete it.

I’m voting to close this question because comments indicate a close.
